# How to populate Data at the top of UIcollectionview Table

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Currently I am using Firebase to store my data, I currently post a uicollectionview cell and it appears at the bottom of the table. I am trying to make the cells appear at the top first. The newly created cell first and then older posts to go down the UIcollectionview. (Just like twitter or instagram). My code below is how I create a cell and save to Firebase.

```
    // MARK: Firebase Database saving posts
    func fetchData() {
        ref?.child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.objects.removeAll()
            snapshot.children.forEach({ (child) in
                if let value = (child as? DataSnapshot)?.value as? [String : Any] {
                    if let imagePath = value["image"] as? String, let title = value["title"] as? String {
                        let aObject = Object(image: nil, imagePath: imagePath, title: title)
                        self.objects.insert(aObject, at:0)
                    }

                }
            })
            self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        })
    }
```

Comment: As @Auila_Sagitta mentioned you can insert the object at the beginning of the array. However, you can also use a NSSortDescriptor to sort the array based on the date or some other value as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you, would you be able to provide me with an example?

Comment: `objects.sort { return $0 < $1 }` [Found here](https://thatthinginswift.com/sort-and-sorted/)

Comment: @AquilaSagitta thank you, still trying to understand how it works!

Comment: @KimRiegel, basically it grabs two object from your array, $0 and $1. Then, checks to see if $0 > $1 (as long as the > operator is defined for those objects). For instance, $0 and $1 is of type `Object` based on your code. If that type has a `date` property then you could do the following: `objects.sort { return $0.date < $1.date }`. This would sort the `Object`'s by date in ascending order.

Comment: @Jonathan thank you, makes it much more clear... If I wanted to create a date property do I make it in swift or is it provided by firebase?

Comment: I've never used Firebase so I'm not sure if you need to add a createdAt and/or modifiedAt property in the DB. Also, I have no idea if you're using custom objects (in Swift) to represent the tables in the DB. If Firebase doesn't store the aforementioned properties you'll have to create them in the DB. If you're using custom objects to represent tables you'll have to add the aforementioned properties in swift as well.

Comment: @Jonathan awesome thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.objects.append(aObject)` should be `self.object.insert(aObject, atIndex: 0)`

Append adds elements to end of array.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, I was appending to the table view instead of just inserting the cells. The new swift 3 syntax is  self.objects.insert(aObject, at: 0)